# Waiting for upload

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have 100 apps in Itunes App Store which I need to update. The main problem is when I add the new version  in the end I need to go one by one and and click Ready To Download, andwer the form questions and click Submit. 
Is there any command line way to do it in XCode or whatever? Who can give a hint?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to fill out anything on iTunes connect via command line/scrip.

Maybe someone can correct me if i'm wrong.

Also, i'm curious.  What are your 100 apps in the store?  That seems like a lot of apps.  Can you give me a link?

Comment: Sorry Karim it's commercial secret. ;)